# How do I remove the unverified tag from unverified Git commits?

Tags: git, github, gnupg

Pretty simple, this has happened and I want to remove the tag from all of them easily. Any way to do so?

[image: Picture of commits page on GitHub]

Only asking as this looks terrible and unpresentable for when I release my project. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

GitHub displays the `unverified` label next to [signed commits](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits) whose signature [can't be verified](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-commit-signature-verification/checking-your-commit-and-tag-signature-verification-status#checking-your-commit-signature-verification-status). It might be due to an [expired GPG key](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-commit-signature-verification/updating-an-expired-gpg-key) or because the key is associated to a [different email address](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/troubleshooting-commit-signature-verification/using-a-verified-email-address-in-your-gpg-key) than the one recorded in the commits' metadata.

To get rid of that label you'll have to either:

1. Renew the GPG key used to sign the commits
2. [Associate the email address](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/associating-an-email-with-your-gpg-key) recorded in the commits to the GPG key used to sign them
3. Remove the signature from the commits altogether

Note that the third alternative involves [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) and all that it entails.